# Should there be an inverse to this relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, relationship, inverse

for a turn-based multiplayer game I'm working on, I defined a **Game** entity to store game information. Each game is player between two registered Users. Since I already had a **User** entity I decided to link the users to the game using a relationship. I defined a **player1** and a **player2** relationship from the **Game** to the **User** entity because I want to explicitly assign each user to one of the two player slots (instead of a to-many **players** relationship where the players are part of a set). I also have a relationship **games** from the **User** entity to the **Game** entity to store all the games that a user is currently involved in.

I can't set an inverse relationship this way, because then my games relationship would have to have an inverse of either **player1** or **player2**. But Xcode is complaining about the lack of inverse, so I'm wondering if I should model my relationships in another way? Here are the Xcode warnings:

> Consistency Error: User.games does not have an inverse; this is an advanced setting (no object can be in multiple destinations for a specific relationship)

and

> Misconfigured Property: Game.player1 should have an inverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve that by defining *two* inverse relationships: `games1` as inverse to `player1`, and `games2` as inverse to `player2`.

Defining inverse relationships is generally recommended, as it helps to keep the integrity
of the object graph. For example, if a user is deleted and the inverse relationship delete
rule is set to "Nullify", then the `player1`/`player2` entry in all related games is set to NULL
and does not point to non-existent user objects.

Comment: I would still need a "games" relationship, because I want to retrieve all the games that a player is involved in, not just the games where he has taken the player1 slot. I guess the object graph would still be inconsistent then?

Comment: @Bart: You *could* define another relationship "games" (which is all games of the user). In that case you actually would leave that *without* an inverse, and ignore the warning. - Alternatively you can *fetch* all games of a user with a simple fetch request on Game with the predicate "player1 = %@ OR player2 = %@". It might even be possible to define that as a "fetched property" on the User entity.

Comment: Ok thanks. I decided to just have a to-many "users" relationship with as inverse "games" that links the two player to the game, and then add "player1" and "player2" attributes to the Game entity that hold just the username for that slot. Thanks for the help.